# How can I deal with Dependency Analysis Warnings? iOS

Tags: ios, dependencies, project-management, compiler-warnings

So our iOS project has been shared amongst our team and I guess some of our files, such as library files, png files, and just some folders have been "lost" over the sharing process.

That being said, our code is performing the way we like, but there are several warnings stating that we have "multiple build commands for the output file", and "directory not found for option".

How can we deal with these warnings without breaking our code?

EDIT: David's answer below eliminates the "multiple build commands for the output file". I still can't handle the "directory not found for option" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple build commands is probably due to the same files being listed multiple times in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.  Two ways to fix it:

1. Select the file in the file browser on the left, select the left most property inspector (the view on the far right) and toggle the check mark under "Target Membership"
2. Select the project in the browser on the left, select the application under targets, select build phases, open your copy bundle resources, find the duplicated entries and delete the spares.

This is a pretty common error for team projects since file connections are given UUID's and almost certainly won't match if multiple people add the same resources.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This was exactly what went wrong and how to fix this issue.

Comment: How can I deal with the "directory not found for option" errors?